# I have a static form template hard copy. I want to add text to it

Tags: php, laravel, document

I have a hard copy of a special formatted document. Building it with html to get back to exact format would be a challenge. The document is standard and got to look the exact same down to the lines and curves. Is there something in Laravel where we can have the template in the printer as letter size. And then just add the text to different position on the letter size page to keep the format.

Answer (score 0):

Make a PDF : image background + generated text.

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query to your css containing print-specific styles

```
@media print {
  ...
}
```

This looks like a good print style resource [here](https://www.jotform.com/blog/css-perfect-print-stylesheet-98272/)